# Split Outlook PST files

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, pst

I have large pst files which I need to split into smaller pst files.  Is this something that can be done?  Where the split pst files remain usable in outlook.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [MS KB Article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932086) has steps to do so in Outlook 2007 **method 3** Your best bet would be to transfer your file to a computer that has 2007 and use one of these methods. This will allow you to work on a *backup* copy as well as you won't have to buy a third-party application to do it. Regardless, **always work on a backup**

> ### Method 3: Split your large .pst file into several smaller .pst files
>
> Use **one** of these **two** methods:

> **Use the Archive feature to move items to a new .pst file. To do this, follow these steps:**
>
> a.  In Outlook 2007, select your .pst file in the navigation pane.
>
> b. On the File menu, click Archive.
>
> c. In the Archive dialog box, click to select the Archive this folder and all
> subfolders check box, and then click a folder from the list.
>
> d. In the Archive items older than drop-down box, click a date.
>
> e. Click Browse, specify a path and a file name for the new .pst file, and then click
> OK.
>
> **Note** The new .pst file is displayed in the Mail Folders list as
> Archive Folders.

### OR

> **Use the Move to Folder feature to move items to a new .pst file. To do this, follow these steps:**
>
> a. On the File menu, point to New, and  then click Outlook Data File.
>
> b.In the New Outlook Data File dialog box, click Office Outlook Personal Folders File (.pst), and then click OK.
>
> c. Specify a path and a file name for the new .pst file.
>
> d. In the Create Microsoft Personal Folders dialog box, specify the display name of the .pst file in the Name box. This is the name that is used by Outlook in the Mail Folders list.
>
> e. In the folder that contains the items that you want to move to a new .pst file, click one or more items to move.
>
> f. On the Edit menu, click Move to Folder.
>
> g. In the Move Items dialog box, click New.
>
> h. In the Create New Folder dialog box, enter a name for the new folder in the Name box.
>
> i. Under Select where to place the folder, click the new .pst file, and then click OK.
>
> j. In the Move Items dialog box, make sure that the new folder in the new .pst file is selected, and then click OK.

*Please forgive my formatting, trying to keep it in a quotation block*

Answer (score 4):

Mentioned (by @Raystafaian) methods are not flexible and way too complex than using **free** [Split Storage](http://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/outlookstoragesplit/) utility. All you need is to specify source storage (your connected PST), destination folder for resulting PST files and desired PST file size. You can also split your PST files by years using this tool.

I recommend this freeware product because I'm one of its developers and this way actually **splits** PSTs automatically without need to manually copy items.

Comment: Will the newly created split files be usable in outlook as archives?  Or will I have to join all the files again to original form before using the archive file?

Comment: All of them are usable immediately after creation. Moreover, the utility can leave these new PSTs connected to your profile.

Comment: for some reason I was unable to use the free version on 64 bit machine.

Comment: @itsho it has to work, please contact support@outlookfreeware.com